# Capture return value from python script into shell script

Tags: python, shell

I have a shell script inside of which I am calling a python script say `new.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

python new.py
```

Now this `new.py` is something like -

```
if not os.path.exists('/tmp/filename'):
    print "file does not exist"
    sys.exit(0)
```

If the file does not exits then the python script returns but the shell script continue execution. I want the shell script also to stop at that point if the file does nt exits and my python script exits.

Please suggest how can I capture the return in shell script to stop its execution further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to return something other than zero from the exit function.

```
if os.path.exists("/tmp/filename"):
    sys.exit(0)
else:
    sys.exit(1)
```

The error value is only 8 bits, so only the lower 8 bits of the integer is returned to the shell. If you supply a negative number, the lower 8 bits of the twos complement representation will be returned, which is probably not what you want. You usually don't return negative numbers.

Comment: I am returning sys.exit(-100) now but in shell echo $? gives 155 ...is it like this number is assigned for these kind of error and can I use it safely like if $? != 0 then exit from the shell

Comment: You could also do `sys.exit(int(not os.path.exists("/tmp/filename")))`, if you so desired

Answer (score 5):

```
if ! python new.py
then
  echo "Script failed"
  exit
fi
```

This assumes that the Python script uses `sys.exit(0)` when your shell script *should continue* and `sys.exit(1)` (or some other non-zero value) when it should stop (it's customary to return a non-zero exit code when an error occurs).